# document.getElementsByName() is not a function in firefox

Tags: javascript, xml, firefox, dom, mozilla

my js code works fine in Chrome and IE, but in Firefox the console says:

> TypeError: xmlDoc.getElementsByName is not a function

```
var nextSectionName = actSection.getElementsByTagName("clickArea")[actClickArea].getAttribute('linkTo');
actSection = xmlDoc.getElementsByName(nextSectionName)[0];
```

The xmlDoc is just a XML file and `actSection = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("section")[0];` works also fine.

Comment: What do you mean by "a XML file"? It has to be a HTML *document*

Comment: Here is a workaround: `xmlDoc.querySelector("[name = '" + nextSectionName + "']");` to get the first. Or use `querySelectorAll` if you want to get them all.

Comment: `getElementsByName()` is part of the HTML DOM, so it won't be available when parsing XML.

Comment: what "name" do expect in a XML file, if not a tagName? XML *(data)* doesn't contain *(HTML)* forms. Why don't you use `getElementsByTagName`? What are you trying to build here?

Answer (score 1):

Certain properties that you know from `window.document` only exist on [HTML documents](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#the-document-object), not on [XML documents](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-document) in general. These include attributes such as `.referrer`, `.head`, `.body` or `.images`, and methods such as `.write()`, `.execCommand()` or `.getElementsByName()`.

In an XML document, you should only use ids and classes, `name` attributes are meaningless. If you absolutely must match names, use an attribute selector.